# extract bounding box dimensions for TrueType font

Tags: command-line, x11, fonts, ttf

On Linux, I can easily extract the height / width / ascent / descent dimensions of Xorg fonts via `xlsfonts`, e.g.

```
$ xlsfonts -ll -fn 9x15 | egrep 'bounds|max'
  bounds:               width left  right  asc  desc   attr   keysym
        max                9     4     9    12     3  0x0000
```

How can I extract the same information from a TrueType font I have installed?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ttf2afm`](http://leuksman.com/linux/ttfutils-3.html) utility, now available in TeXlive, extracts AFM from a TrueType font (as the name suggests). AFM stands for [Adobe Font Metrics](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/5004.AFM_Spec.pdf), and is a text format which is simple to parse. Here's a sample:

```
StartCharMetrics 10538
C -1 ; WX 600 ; N .notdef ; B 34 -71 566 750 ;
C -1 ; WX 0 ; N .null ; B 130 -9 237 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 333 ; N CR ; B 130 -9 237 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 600 ; N CR ; B 130 -9 237 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 250 ; N space ; B 130 -9 237 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 333 ; N exclam ; B 130 -9 237 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 400 ; N quotedbl ; B 73 431 327 676 ;
C -1 ; WX 500 ; N numbersign ; B 5 0 496 662 ;
C -1 ; WX 500 ; N dollar ; B 44 -87 457 727 ;
```

Each line in this section is a list of values about one character, separated by semicolons. `WX` is the character width. `N` is the character name; use `ttf2afm -u` to print Unicode code points like `uni0020`. `B` is the bounding box (x_left, y_bottom, x_right, y_top).